# jQuery - mouseOver change div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onmouseover

I have a menu that on each  item's  mouseover event  an image loaded into a second div should change, and onMouseout it should replace with the original content.

At this point I am saving the original content into a var and creating a onMouseover & onMouseOut event each for each menu item.

**Jquery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var heroSwap= $('#swapspace').html();

    $('#menu1').mouseover(function(){
        $('#swapspace').html('<img src="img/1.JPG"></img>');

    });
    $('#menu1').mouseout(function(){

        $('#swapspace').html(heroSwap);

    });
    .... ..*ETC  There are 7 More of these identical except for id*.. ....

});
```

**Question:**

1. Is there any way to create a generic function that can process a parameter from the menu tag?
2. Would it be easier.. instead of swapping the innerHTML img tags to create hidden divs that are displayed/hidden by the onMouseover/onMouseout events?

**Full Sample:**
[Sample Site](http://elgee123.net23.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generic function easily. You can add on the `#menu1` tag an attribute with the url of your image and a class name like that :

```
 <li class='menu' data-src='img/1.JPG'></li>
```

And then create the function like that :

```
$('.menu').mouseover(function(){
    $('#swapspace').html('<img src="'+$(this).data('src')+'"></img>');

});
$('.menu').mouseout(function(){

    $('#swapspace').html(heroSwap);

});
```

As for your second question, i would simply swap the `src` of you `img` instead of changing the entire HTML.

```
$('#swapspace').find('img').attr('src', $(this).data('src')); //on hover
$('#swapspace').find('img').attr('src', ''); //on out
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better that you store the image src in the `data-src`  attribute. So that you need not use multiple variables for each image.

Then you would not need to change the html, just changing the `src` attribute would do the trick.

Firstly replace your `li` to use `class` instead of `id's`

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked nav-pills">
    <li class="menu" data-src="img/1.JPG"> <a href="#">Web Development</a> </li>
    <li class="menu" data-src="img/2.JPG"> <a href="#">Software Development</a></li>
    <li class="menu" data-src="img/3.JPG"> <a href="#">System Support</a></li>
    <li class="menu" data-src="img/4.JPG"> <a href="#">SEO</a></li>
    <li class="menu" data-src="img/5.JPG"> <a href="#">Social Media Marketing</a> </li>
    <li class="menu" data-src="img/6.JPG"> <a href="#">Project Management</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $swapImg = $('img', '#swapspace'),
        defaultImage = 'default.jpg';

    $('.menu').on({
        mouseover: function () {
            $swapImg.attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
        },
        mouseout: function () {
             $swapImg.attr('src', defaultImage);
        }
    })
});
```

This way you would have **only one event handler** for all the `li's` , instead of a **separate handler for each menu item.**

Comment: this would great but I am swapping a <p> for an <img>. I am definatly going to use the data-src tags though they are exactly what i was looking for !

Answer (score 1):

It's actually better to use css for this. It's easier too.

The background can be anything in css, url, color etc.

```
<div id="menu1" class="menu-item"><div class="img"></div></div>
<div id="menu2" class="menu-item"><div class="img"></div></div>
```

cont'd.

Simple js hover uses mouseenter and mouseleave http://api.jquery.com/hover/

```
$(function() {

    $(".menu-item").hover(function() {
       $(this).addClass("hover"); 
    }, function() {
       $(this).removeClass("hover");
    });

});
```

Then markup your images with css:

```
.menu-item {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.img {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ddd;
}

.menu-item.hover .img {
    background: #000;   
}

#menu2.hover .img {
    background: url("http://placehold.it/200x30") no-repeat;
}

#menu4.hover .img {
    background: url("http://placehold.it/200x30") no-repeat;
}
```

You can preload the images as well by using sprite sheets instead of javascript loading images in the background.

http://jsfiddle.net/E6xtq/1/